# How to assign a CKEditor profile to a specific field?

Tags: wysiwyg

I'm learning Drupal and right now CKEditor.
I want my website to have a blog, with a complex editor for the articles, and a much simpler one for the comments. I have created two different profiles in CKEditor, but now I'm stuck and don't know what to do next...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CKeditor profiles are assigned to text formats (admin/config/content/formats).

Ckeditor is available for "Long text" fields. When editing the field, you have to choose "Filtered text", so, if a Ckeditor profile is assigned to this format, when creating or editing the node, Ckeditor appears.

Comment: Also keep in mind that text formats are allocated to users via role permissions. By default their order is determined by the weights assigned in the text format config area. You can override the default on the individual field settings, but the user will still see the change format ui on the rendered page. There are various ways to hide the format selector ui so the user doesn't get confused (I don't find this format handling particularly intuitive)